# How to choose our data set wisely?

Tags: classification, datasets, object-detection

I have a couple of questions and I was wondering if you could answer them.

I have a bunch of images of the cars, side view only. I want to train the model with those images. My objects of interest are **3 types of trucks** that have different trailers. I Rarely see two target object at one image (maybe 1 or 2 in every 1000 images). However, I do see other types of cars that I do not want to detect.

My questions are:

1. Do you think I should tackle this problem as a detection task or classification task? (for example, should I consider multi-label classification or omit those pictures)
2. Should I also include other vehicles that I do not want to detect in my training dataset? let say I do not assign bounding box to them but include them in training dataset just to make the system robust.

I trained YOLO with 200 images, sometimes the trained model confused and detected the wrong object that is not in any of classes, this happens when training with 2000 images per class?

Is this due to a small number of dataset or it is because of not including those images with no bounding boxes?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the community! Perhaps adding a few links (e.g. YOLO) and including some samples of your images would help readers understand the case better.